# Error when Echoing from 'mysqli_fetch_array' in PHP using Loop

Tags: php, arrays, string

This is my syntax:

```
//... just database connection as usual

$callDatabase = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from `it-is-my-db`.`employee`");
echo "<table border=\"1\">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>";

        while($databaseRow = mysqli_fetch_array($callDatabase,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo 
            "
            <tr>
                <td>$databaseRow['EmployeeID']</td>       //this is Line 81 where the error occured
                <td>$databaseRow['Name']</td>
                <td>$databaseRow['Address']</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        };
```

And this is the result:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\xampp\htdocs\some-folder\php.php on line 81`

I think the single quote `''` is true syntax, since I tried double quotes `""` and it fails.

Comment: You need to leave out the single quotes around the array key, when you are accessing an array variable inside a double-quoted string like this. Or use one of the different syntaxes, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Save yourself the escaping headache and just write `?><tr><td><?php echo $databaseRow['EmployeeID']; ?></td><td><?php echo $databaseRow['Name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $databaseRow['Address']; ?></td></tr><?php`

Comment: Or `echo "<tr><td>".$databaseRow["EmployeeID"]."</td><td>".$databaseRow["Name"]."</td><td>".$databaseRow["Address"]."</td></tr>";`

Comment: Or maybe `echo "<tr><td>$databaseRow[EmployeeID]</td><td>$databaseRow[Name]</td><td>$databaseRow[Address]</td></tr>";` . There are plenty of examples already of how to include an item from an array into a PHP string, if you care to look online

Comment: It is funny everytime I asked about PHP and there's always instant dislike 